# Migrating polling to SignalR without polling on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, polling

I have a piece of functionality in my web application that kicks off a long running report on my server. Currently, I have an ajax method on my client that is constantly running to check if the currently running report is complete. It does this by repeatedly calling a method that queries the database to determine if a given report's status has changed from `Running` to either `Error` or `Complete`. Once the report is finished, I perform an ajax load to get the data.

I'm looking at implementing SignalR to add some additional functionality to other pages, and I figured this would be a good test case to get things going. My main concern is how to alert the client when the report is complete. Using SignalR, I can simply say something like:

```
public class ReportHub : Hub
{
    public async Task ReportComplete(string userId, ReportRunStatus guid)
    {
        await Clients.User(userId).SendAsync("ReportComplete", guid);
    }
}
```

However, I want to try to avoid putting a long running loop on the server as I'm afraid this could degrade performance as operations scale up. Is there a better way to handle checking the report status and alerting clients than simply polling until completion? Or is there some easy way to constantly be looking at the table and alerting on completed reports?

Comment: You could create a queue and whenever the report is completed it posts a message to the queue indicating the success/failure result. The web server has a thread that waits on the queue for a message and when one arrives it performs the ReportComplete as needed. That avoids the need for polling.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It sounds like I'd still need to poll the queue looking to see if there is anything in it. Granted, that sounds like minimal overhead.

Comment: Can't this be simply done with an event? When the report is complete it fires an event. You have a service/class listening for the event and then calls the SignalrR hub (or whatever you want) to indicate the report is ready? Even your Hub could listen for the event? Or am I over simplifying it and missing the nuances of your question?

Comment: @SimplyGed I don't think that will quite work with our implementation. The report runner lives in our logic layer. It kicks off the report run asynchronously and passes back a GUID to the controller for the user's browser to use as a key to poll with. However, the report runner simply runs all the widgets on the report then sets the status of the report to done. It can't really call out to the Web layer.